# Add subview to current view's UINavigationBar only

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uikit

What I want to do is add a custom view to my UINavigationController's `UINavigationBar` but only for the current visible view controller.

So I build the subviews of the view I want to add in a container view and this view to the navigation bar by getting a reference with:

```
let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar as UINavigationBar!
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

However, when I push another view controller in the `UINavigationController` stack, this subview persists in the `UINavigationBar` of the pushed viewControllers as well:

[image]

What's the best way to add this subview only in my current view's `UINavigationBar` and don't have it persisted on consecutive view controllers as well?

Comment: I think the best way is to save what you have in the status bar in `viewWillAppear` and recover them in `viewWillDisappear`. Sorry, I am not sure about these two methods' counterparts in swift. But the idea is the same.

Comment: Use UINavigationControllerDelegate methods willShowViewController didShowViewController to add and remove the view, it will simplify your things lot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is happening for a few reasons:

1. Adding a subview to a `UINavigationBar` isn't exactly unsupported, but could possibly result in odd behavior.
2. All view controllers in a `UINavigationController` share the same `UINavigationBar` (which is why a newly pushed view controller didn't have any affect on your subview).

If you want to do this properly, here's two possible solutions:

1. Use `viewWillAppear` and `viewWillDisappear` to add/show and remove/hide your subview when your ideal view controller is visible.
2. Use `UINavigationItem`'s  `titleView` property to assign this view, e.g.:

   ```
   // Example code in Obj-C, sorry!
   myViewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[MySearchView alloc] init];
   ```

   This way the search view will be unique to that view controller.

Comment: what are the bounds of title view? Can it facilitate a view that expands almost full width like this? This sounds like the best option to me.

Comment: @Thanos It should allow you to expand it to full width (provided there are not left and right items). When I've done this once before I was able to set the `titleView`'s frame to the full navigation bar with with no problems.

Comment: How to use autolayout with the second option?